# Subtract two numbers using Linked List in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, linked-list

Write a program to subtract two numbers represented in form of linked list in python given lead pointers.

Comment: Welcome ot SO unfortunatelySO is not a code writting service you have to show what you tried and give a specific error or problem you encountered. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have the classes for a linked list, although do let me know if you need to define one of those yourself. Given a linked list (say LL) you can say the difference is given simply by the head nodes (lead pointer) data minus the node after the head.

that will look like this in python:

```
# assumed there is some linked list defined like LL
difference = LL.head.data - LL.head.next.data
```